# I cannot find the ungetcflag member of FILE structure according to fgetc(FILE*) implementation

Tags: c, stdio, libc

This is the implementation of the function `int fgetc(FILE* fp)` according to this link. [mirror.fsf.org](http://mirror.fsf.org/pmon2000/2.x/src/lib/libc/fgetc.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/**  fgetc(fp) -- get char from stream */

int fgetc(FILE *fp)
{
    char c;

    if (fp->ungetcflag) {
        fp->ungetcflag = 0;
        return (fp->ungetchar);
    }
    if (read (fp->fd, &c, 1) == 0)
        return (EOF);
    return (c);
}
```

I tried looking at the definition of `FILE` in `stdio.h` and google and I couldn't find the member `ungetcflag` or `ungetchar`.

What is the meaning of this?

Comment: That is **one** implementation of `fgetc`, not **the** implementation of `fgetc`. Specifically it is **not the implementation of `fgetc`** that is your libc, hence the code does not match the `FILE` definition in **your** `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: There is a C library function called `ungetc` that allows characters to be pushed back onto an input stream. This is just one way to support that function. The implementation that you looked at may use a different mechanism.

Comment: That library's `<stdio.h>` is at http://mirror.fsf.org/pmon2000/2.x/src/include/stdio.h. The contents of `FILE` are opaque, you're not supposed to know them - except that the actual definition can still be available to facilitate writing macros such as `getc` in the system headers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54017500/i-cannot-find-the-ungetcflag-member-of-file-structure-according-to-fgetcfile#comment94871486_54017500) comment good enough for an answer.

That is **one** implementation of `fgetc()`, not **the** implementation of `fgetc)_`.
 Specifically it is **not the implementation of `fgetc()`** that is your libc, hence the code does not match the `FILE` definition in your `<stdio.h>`.